# A-posteriori error bounds in computing eigenvalues

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, book-recommendation, condition-number

Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be diagonalizable
$$ A = P^{-1} \Lambda P $$
Let $\widetilde{\lambda}$, $\widetilde{u}$ be an approximate eigenpair of $A$ with residual vector $r = A\widetilde{u} - \widetilde{\lambda}\widetilde{u}$, where $\|\widetilde{u}\|_2 = 1$. Then it is known that there exists an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that
$$ |\lambda - \widetilde{\lambda}| \le \text{cond}_2 P \|r\|_2, $$
where $\text{cond}_2 P$ is the condition number of $P$.

Also there is a notion of the condition number of a simple eigenvalue
$$ \text{cond} (\lambda) = \dfrac{\|u\|_2 \|w\|_2}{|w^*u|}, $$
where $u$ and $w$ are the right and left eigenvectors, respectively, associated with $\lambda$. Moreover
$$ \text{cond}_2(P) \ge \text{cond}(\lambda) $$
for any eigenvalue $\lambda$. It seems to me that the estimate
$$ |\lambda - \widetilde{\lambda}| \le \text{cond}_2 P \|r\|_2 $$
is rather rough, since it provides the estimate using the whole matrix $P$, but not the individual condition number of the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Are there any estimates of the form
$$ |\lambda - \widetilde{\lambda}| \le \text{cond} (\lambda) \|r\|_2 ?$$

I will be glad to any books, articles, ideas and examples on this topic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I replaced the tag linear-algebra with numerical linear algebra to increase the chance that your question reaches the right people. I am very tired right now, but I doubt very much that what you seek is possible. The two first books to check are Wilkinson's "The Algebraic Eigenvalue Problem" and G.W. Stewart's "Matrix algorithms" vol. 2. Wilkinsons does an amazing job squeezing maximum information out of Gershgorin's circle theorem with a very low level analysis. In any case, I would be delighted to discover that I am wrong!